# how to clear listview

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a ListView that displays an array that is generated dynamically by the user from within the activity. Basically, the program is a timer and the user can choose a time they would like an alarm to go off and also provide a description of what they should be doing when that alarm goes off.

I have the ListView setup using a SimpleAdapter which calls a alarm_list_item.xml, which contains two TextView's and an icon that I want displayed for each item in the list.

```
package com.example.sa_one.api;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public String str;
    String data2[] = new String[50];
    String data;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                client.get("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/", null, new api());

                CustomList adapter = new CustomList(getApplicationContext(),data2);
                ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + data2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    class api extends AsyncHttpResponseHandler {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int i, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
                Log.e("responce ss", "" + str);


                try {
                    JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(str);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("contacts");
                    int lengthJsonArr = jsonArray.length();

                    for (i = 0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = jsonObject.optString("id");
                        String name = jsonObject.optString("name");
                        String email = jsonObject.optString("email");
                        String address = jsonObject.optString("address");
                        String gender = jsonObject.optString("gender");

                        data = "Node" + i + " : \n id= " + id + " \n Name= " + name + " \n Email= " + email + " \n address= " + address + "\n gender=" + gender + "\n\n";
                        Log.i("responce s1", "" + data);

                        data2[i] = data;


                        Log.i("responce s2", "" + Arrays.toString(data2));
                    }


                } catch (JSONException ignored) {

                }

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int i, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {

        }
    }
}
```

this code give error to me
When the user chooses not to add a custom dialog for the alarm I would like to set the visibility of the TextView in alarm_list_item.xml to GONE so it doesn't show as a blank space on the list. When I try to set this parameter from within the activity I get a NullPointerException because I am assuming that the xml file isn't actually an object but more or less just used as a reference for the ListView. Is there a way to accomplish this?

So far I am getting around the problem by setting the text to "No Custom Notification Set" but i'd like a cleaner option and just remove the line all together when its not in use.

Comment: You'd probably get more help if you added a tag for the programming language/tools you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pYou can grab the TextView by findViewById(). So in your onItemClick() use the following code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.your_textview);
    tv.setVisibility(GONE);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + data2,     
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```